# How do I create a MySQL user with a wildcard domain?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to setup a MySQL server that can be accessed by anyone on our internet network.

I can connect, via PHP, to the server using localhost, but not with my IP as hostname:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'user.corp.companyname.com' (using password: YES) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/doc.php on line 38
```

I've setup the same MySQL user using the hosts localhost, %, and *, but MySQL still doesn't seem to accept unknown hosts.

**Update**

Well, I give up: other machines on the network seem to have no problem making the MySQL connection, so it's just my local machine that refuses to authenticate when using my IP as the host.

Comment: So you're saying `[user]@%` doesn't work?

Comment: @Matt yeah, that's correct. I setup this user: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '[user]'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: What about `[user]@user.corp.companyname.com`?

Comment: @nipponese And `IDENTIFIED BY`?

Comment: @Matt the problem is the `user` in `user.corp` will be different for every user on the network.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, that won't work, then.

Comment: @Matt I `DROP`ed the user and recreated it, thinking maybe I forgot to add a password for that case, but after creating it again using `CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` still no joy.